# Undo checkbox changes on modal close

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap modal that contain 3 checkboxes. 2 are checked. I want to do something like this
When a user opens modal & make changes to checkbox. if he closes the modal i want the checkboxes to go back to the way they were when modal was opened. Is there a way it can be done in jquery

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel"><i class="icon-bar-chart"> </i> Modules</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <label class="checkbox ">
  <input type="checkbox"  value="option1" checked> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  value="option2" checked> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  value="option3"> 3
</label>

    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="modsave">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>


<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
    Launch demo modal</a>
```

Found a way to do this but it stops working when you make change & close modal the second time

```
var clone=$("#myModal .modal-body").clone();


$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {


  $("#myModal .modal-body").html(clone);
});
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aPDVM/172/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working now. Used html instead on clone

```
var clone=$("#myModal .modal-body").html(); //instead of clone


$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {


  $("#myModal .modal-body").html(clone);
});
```

Jsiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aPDVM/176/